# How to reorg the indexes in DB2 database

Tags: db2

I have to reorg all the index for table

I am getting the following error

> SQL Error [23505]: One or more values in the INSERT statement, UPDATE statement, or foreign key update caused by a DELETE statement are not valid because the primary key, unique constraint or unique index identified by "2" constrains table "GMS4.SMS_PHYSICAL_CUSTOMER_DATA" from having duplicate values for the index key.. SQLCODE=-803, SQLSTATE=23505, DRIVER=4.16.53
>     One or more values in the INSERT statement, UPDATE statement, or foreign key update caused by a DELETE statement are not valid because the primary key, unique constraint or unique index identified by "2" constrains table "GMS4.SMS_PHYSICAL_CUSTOMER_DATA" from having duplicate values for the index key.. SQLCODE=-803, SQLSTATE=23505, DRIVER=4.16.53

DB2 Version 10

Please help..

Comment: You are trying to insert a duplicate value, which one of your constraints does not allow. How do you suppose reorganizing indexes could resolve that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're on DB2 for Linux/Unix/Windows, here.

Your problem is not that you need to reorg your tables. The problem is that you are trying to insert a row, but you have a unique index on that table, which is preventing the insert.

You can see the name of the index, and the columns it is unique for by using this query:

```
SELECT 
     I.INDSCHEMA
    ,I.INDNAME
    ,C.COLNAME
FROM SYSCAT.INDEXES     I
JOIN SYSCAT.INDEXCOLUSE C
  ON I.INDSCHEMA = C.INDSCHEMA
 AND I.INDNAME   = C.INDNAME
WHERE I.IID       = @indexID
  AND I.TABSCHEMA = @tableSchema
  AND I.TABNAME   = @tableName
ORDER BY C.COLSEQ
;
```

You can get all of the parameters needed for this query from your error message. In this case, `@indexId` would be `2`, `@tableSchema` would be `GMS4`, and `@tableName` would be `SMS_PHYSICAL_CUSTOMER_DATA`.